# ASP.NET System.Web.Routing and Querystring Parameters

Tags: asp.net, routes, system.web.routing

I am using ASP.Net 3.5 SP1 "System.Web.Routing" to enable URL routing in my WebForm Application. Now what i needed is to pass some parameters in QueryString eg:

http://www.mydomain.com/Search/Books/Computers?sort=author&pagesize=10

This is the route i am using:

```
        routes.Add("BooksSearch", new Route
        (
           "Search/{Category}/{Product}",
           new CustomRouteHandler("~/Search.aspx")
        ));
```

Route is working fine as it is redirected to search.aspx but in querystring i can't find extra parameters sort & pagesize.

Comment: i am still unable to find a way to get it working.. any pointers?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to add them to your route, as they will be processed normally.

The parameters are inside your `Request.Params` collection and inside tyour `Request.QueryString` collection.

Comment: Request.Params["sort"] and Request.QueryString["sort"] both returns null. I think that is because CustomRouteHandler initialize target page dynamically without any QueryString params.

Comment: From your acceptance I take it that you have found your missing parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Please Use

Page.RouteData.Values["ID"]

instead of

Request.QueryString["ID"]

Thanks